# Google sheets NO_COLUMN error regardless of solving the syntax or trying different formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i am doing a customer history sheet where i just take the data from another sheet using importrange as the query data and i am selecting what i want to take out of that history in my new customer history sheet.
but will all the trials i've made it just give me NO_COLUMN

i've also used the 'Col4' syntax not the label and still nothing :(

the formula:
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1GT5Or0kgEjgJEDLhFHju81x9rg1geuQrBrCHawSq-to", "Order tracking!D2:E528"), "SELECT Col4 WHERE Col5 = '"&B2&"'", 0)

i tried the 'ColX' syntax not the label, tried to do special data range in every cell with the data i want to take out instead of A:Z columns and still gives the same error.

Comment: If the range you are importing is `D2:E`; then `D` would be `Col1` and `E` is `Col2`